# Is it possible to fill two objects with arrays in a forEach function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

Is it possible to fill two objects with arrays in a forEach function and output them as seperate variables? I want to have a two variables called geojson and geojson2. I know I can copy paste the code and do it seperate for each one of the variables, but it's lot cleaner if I can do it in just one foreach function. 
I commented out the second variable in the code below so it's clear what I added for the second variable. I tryed the code, but I get this error when I run it:
`TypeError: d.split is not a function`.

```
        geojson = {
            "type": "FeatureCollection",
            "features": []
        };

        geojson2 = {
            "type": "FeatureCollection",
            "features": []
        };

        var dataArray = data.split(", ;");
        dataArray.pop();

        dataArray.forEach(function(d,e){
            d = d.split(", "); 
            //e = e.split(", "); 

            var feature = {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {}, //properties object container
                "geometry": JSON.parse(d[fieldList.length]) //parse geometry
            };

            for (var i=0; i<fieldList.length; i++){
                if ([fieldList[i].show_field] == 't') {
                    feature.properties[fieldList[i].field_alias] = d[i];
                } else {
                    //feature.properties[fieldList[i].field_name] = e[i];    
                }
            };
            geojson.features.push(feature);
            //geojson2.features.push(feature);
            console.log(geojson);
        });
```

Comment: What does your `data` variable contain?

Comment: Data contains this:`"53.211348999999998, 6.564192000000000, BurgerKing, BurgerKing, 482, 11, 0101000020AD100000CAA8328CBB411A406A85E97B0D9B4A40, {"type":"Point","coordinates":[6.564192,53.211349]}, ;53.218551800000000, 6.565729900000000, BurgerKing, BurgerKing, 519, 12, 0101000020AD100000377AEBB24E431A40B0BD6081F99B4A40, {"type":"Point","coordinates":[6.5657299,53.2185518]}, ;"`

Comment: But I dont think it has anything to do with `data` because when I run the code with only `d` in the `foreach` it works. So I think it has to do something with having `d,e` in the foreach? @zadaz

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve here. The commented line where you call e.split() will attempt to split an integer (second param of forEach).

Comment: I need `e` to do exactly the same as `d` only at the for loop I want it to do something different. If i turn around `  d = d.split(", ");` and  `//e = e.split(", "); ` it will give me the same error only than for `d`. @Cobus Kruger So te be short I need `geojson = all d[i]'s` and geojson2 =`all e[i]'s`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can provide source string and data object that needs to be generated form it, there might be a way to do regex to extract required data instead of loops and splits.
If you're trying to do within one loop you can move all your non repeating code in single loop. But this is still not pretty,

```
dataArray.forEach(function(d){
d = d.split(", "); 

var feature = {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {}, 
    "geometry": JSON.parse(d[fieldList.length]) 
};
var feature2 = feature;

for (var i=0; i<fieldList.length; i++){
    if ([fieldList[i].show_field] == 't') {
        feature.properties[fieldList[i].field_alias] = d[i];
    }
    feature2.properties[fieldList[i].field_name] = d[i]; 
};
geojson.features.push(feature);
geojson2.features.push(feature2);
console.log(geojson);
});
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! In the comments of my question I posted what `data` contains. Do you mean that by source string and data objects?

Comment: Yes, I see the data string but not sure what fieldList is.

Comment: `FieldList` is an array of all my column names. @hasnat

Comment: Like I said in my answer, and example of data string and end result object you want would be help in providing best practices .